# Поддерживает ли Silverlight асинхронную подгрузку контента и за счёт какого механизма?

Tags: silverlight

Хочу сделать RIA на Silverlight. Посоветуйте, стоит ли браться, и где описан асинхронный механизм. Подойдёт ли следующий механизм: [ссылка](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1759240) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, не стоит. Майкрософт прикрыла эту технологию. С 2011 года новой версии не выходило и, [скорее всего, не будет](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/will-there-be-a-silverlight-6-and-does-it-matter/11180).